# Is it possible to select a specific tab in OSX Terminal.app using keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, osx-leopard

I know I can cycle through my tabs using cmd+{ or cmd+}, but is it possible to select a specific tab (i.e. cmd+3 for the third tab in iTerm) in Leopards' Terminal.app?

Comment: What is wrong with my question? Why do people vote it down?

Comment: It's not really a programming question. I have a shiney new Mac and as much as it is tempting to ask stuff like this here, I just slap myself and go somewhere else. :)

Comment: I've been asking around and searching the web for this; couldn't really find a solution. I find it to be closely related to programming productivity.

Comment: Perhaps, but so is the search for a UK A1048 keyboard for my new mac to replace the crappy aluminium thing they seem to think is ergonomic....that affects my productivity, but I still wouldn't ask. :-)

Comment: Well I find that interesting to ask since the information is hard to find and the terminal is indeed something most programmers are expected to use on a daily basis. It's not another "what's your favorite algorithm" entertainment-only poll.

Comment: hey, cool question!  I didn't even realize that terminal.app *has* tabs.  thx!
|K<

Comment: This question might be better posed on SuperUser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an option. [Tab Switching in Terminal](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/12/10/tab-switching-in-terminal)

Answer (score 0):

*Yes it is, you use Command-1, Command-2 etc.
Have a look under the **Window** menu, and you'll see the windows listed with their shortcut equivalent. (The 'clover-leaf' is the symbol for the Command key - also known as the Apple key.)*

My apologies - missed the fact you were referring to Tabs first time around. I don't believe there is any other keyboard shortcut to switch between Tabs beyond Cmd-{ and }. Perhaps if that's important, don't group them in the first place? Leave them as separate windows?

Comment: That is for windows, not tabs.

Answer (score -2):

I would highly suggest using [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) if you really need tabs that much. I have a particular .screenrc file that makes life easier, just put the following in your home directory in a file called `.screenrc`:

```
defscrollback 1024
hardstatus on
hardstatus alwayslastline
hardstatus string "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %m/%d %C%a "
```

Also, when starting screen, I run `screen -c ~/.screenrc.programming` which looks like this:

```
source $HOME/.screenrc

screen -t World
screen -t Server
screen -t Console
screen -t Command
screen -t Editor
screen -t MySQL
```

This will open a bunch of 'tabs' that you can switch between using `Ctrl-A,n` and `Ctrl-A,p` or `Ctrl-A` followed by a number to switch directly to one.